# Bug in VS2008 compiler : DLL cannot be found

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, visual-studio-2008

I made some changes to my solution which contains a couple of project and wanted to compile it again .. now it says Metadata file C:\myproject\bin\myproject.DLL could not be found...
I closed the VS and opened again and also deleted the bin and obj folder of that project, but still the same compile error...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove and re-add your reference.

Comment: This fixed it. Thanks.  Is it a Bug with VS? what had happened?

Comment: Not a bug.  As mentioned by @Franci Penov it could be that you were referencing the DLL in an output / bin directory that after a build and/or cleaning disappeared/changed. You want to either do a project reference which will always use the latest DLL for the project as it was last built OR reference the DLL in a folder you know isn't changing.

Answer (score 2):

There is something somewhere in your projects that tells the build to look for that dll. Most probably you have a reference in one of the other projects that doesn't reference the project, but references the project output directly.

Comment: And may be looking for a specific version of the DLL.

Comment: well Ok, I checked the References for all other projects, if it is missing it should show it with a Yellow exclamation icon, Right?... but there is no Yellow icon in the references of the projets

Answer (score 1):

This usually means one of the projects that other projects depend on in your solution isn't building correctly.  Make sure you fix all errors and 'rebuild all'.